# interchanging the order of integration (from calculus)

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to interchange the order of the following integral $$I:=\int_0^\pi\int_0^3\int_0^{9-r^2}r^2dzdrd\theta$$
How can we find the boundaries $a,b,c,d,e,f$ of the integral
$$I=\int_a^b\int_c^d\int_e^f r^2drdzd\theta ?$$
I know that $I=\frac{162}{5}\pi$.

Comment: Try to draw the solid...

Comment: It is the region above the plane $z = 0$ and below the paraboloid $z = 9-x^2-y^2$.

Comment: I am sure that $a=0$ and $b=\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed in the comments, the region is the volume under the paraboloid $z= 9-x^2-y^2$ with $z\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$ therefore

$$I=\int_0^\pi\int_0^9\int_0^{\sqrt{9-z}} r^2drdzd\theta$$

Comment: I see the picture now. Thanks!

Comment: @ErginSuer You are welcome! Bye